correct placement of "shape" in [what shape hats] or [what hat shape] or [what shape of]
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) What shape hats do you like?
(1b) What hat shape do you like?
(1c) What shape of hats do you like?
Which one is correct? Thanks.

If the expected answer is something like "top hat" or "baseball hat," then "shape" might not be the best way to ask; "kind of hat" or "style of hat" might be better, and 1c would work best with all of them. Some other topics might be more flexible, e.g. substitute "flavor" and "ice cream" for "shape" and "hat," and all three work. But 1c is probably most flexible.

Any of your three would be fine. There is a very subtle difference in meaning between your 1a and 1b: the former is fundamentally a question about hats, while the latter is fundamentally about shapes. But that’s a distinction so fine as to be irrelevant in nearly any context.

And 1c is even more about shapes.
